# items aren't appearing till after hovering in Jcombobox

Tags: java, swing

I can see the first item selected in the combobox but when I click it there are no items visible, only when i scroll over them can I see the names..

```
 String[] countries  =   Locale.getISOCountries();
 ArrayList countryList = new ArrayList();
 for(String contCode : countries)
 {
     Locale contr    =   new Locale("", contCode);
     //countryField.addItem(contr.getDisplayCountry());
     countryList.add(contr.getDisplayCountry());
 }
 countryField = new JComboBox(countryList.toArray());
```

Comment: You mean the place of the other items are reserved, but contains only white-spaces until you hover your mouse over them? If that's the case try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Don't forget to `pack()` the enclosing `Window`; see also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @ihsan yes, this is what it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/XUyRtJk.png

Comment: As hinted at by @trashgod, this might be a threading issue. Are you setting up/modifying the combo box outside of Swing's Event Dispatcher Thread?

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can duplicate the problem?